# Как сделать распознавание слов умнее?

Tags: python, распознавание-символов, распознавание

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что распознавание каких-либо слов не происходит. Так же очень высокий шанс ошибки программы. Можно ли сделать этот код умнее? Если да, то как? Если нет, то что можно сделать чтобы распознавание слов было с более меньшей ошибкой?

```
import string

words = ["банан", "помидор", 'сингулярность',"канан","починка"]

#print("Фильтруемые слова:", words)

#Фраза, которую будем проверять.
phrase = input("Введите фразу для проверки: ").lower().replace(" ", "")

def distance(a, b): 
    "Calculates the Levenshtein distance between a and b."
    n, m = len(a), len(b)
    if n > m:
        # Make sure n <= m, to use O(min(n, m)) space
        a, b = b, a
        n, m = m, n

    current_row = range(n + 1)  # Keep current and previous row, not entire matrix
    for i in range(1, m + 1):
        previous_row, current_row = current_row, [i] + [0] * n
        for j in range(1, n + 1):
            add, delete, change = previous_row[j] + 1, current_row[j - 1] + 1, previous_row[j - 1]
            if a[j - 1] != b[i - 1]:
                change += 1
            current_row[j] = min(add, delete, change)

    return current_row[n]

d =   {'а' : ['а', 'a', '@',  '*'],
  'б' : ['б', '6', 'b',',','/s'],
  'в' : ['в', 'b', 'v'],
  'г' : ['г', 'r', 'g','u'],
  'д' : ['д', 'd'],
  'е' : ['е', 'e', 't', '**'],
  'ё' : ['ё', 'e',  '***'],
  'ж' : ['ж', 'zh',],
  'з' : ['з', '3', 'z','p'],
  'и' : ['и', 'u', 'i','&','1','!',  '^'],
  'й' : ['й', 'u', 'i', 'i','q'],
  'к' : ['к', 'k', 'i{', 'r','|{'],
  'л' : ['л', 'l', 'ji'],
  'м' : ['м', 'm'],
  'н' : ['н', 'h', 'n','y','№','y'],
  'о' : ['о', 'o', '0',  '*'],
  'п' : ['п', 'n', 'p'],
  'р' : ['р', 'r', 'p'],
  'с' : ['с', 'c', 's','5'],
  'т' : ['т', 'm', 't'],
  'у' : ['у', 'y', 'u', 'e', '*'],
  'ф' : ['ф', 'f'],
  'х' : ['х', 'x', 'h' , 'X', 'Х', 'H', '}{'],
  'ц' : ['ц', 'c', 'u,','w'],
  'ч' : ['ч', 'ch'],
  'ш' : ['ш', 'sh','i'],
  'щ' : ['щ', 'sch','o'],
  'ь' : ['ь', 'b'],
  'ы' : ['ы', 'bi',  '*'],
  'ъ' : ['ъ'],
  'э' : ['э', 'e',  '*'],
  'ю' : ['ю', 'io',  '*'],
  'я' : ['я', 'ya',  '*']
}

а = {
  'a' : ['а', 'a', '@','f', 'эй', '*'],
  'b' : ['б', '6', 'b', 'в', 'b', 'v', 'B', 'Б','би','/s'],
  'c' : ['с', 'c', 's','5'],
  'd' : ['д', 'd', 'D','Д'],
  'e' : ['е', 'e', 'Е', '**'],
  'f' : ['ф', 'f'],
  'h' : ['эйч','эйчь'],
  'g' : ['г', 'r', 'g', 'g', 'Г', 'джи'],
  'i' : ['и', 'u', 'i','&','1','!', 'ай', '^'],
  'j' : ['джи', 'джей'],
  'k' : ['к', 'k', 'i{', '|{'],
  'l' : ['л', 'l', 'ji'],
  'm' : ['м', 'm'],
  'n' : ['н', 'h', 'n','№','y','n'],
  'o' : ['о', 'o', '0',  '*'],
  'p' : ['п', 'n', 'p'],
  'q' : ['ку', 'q', 'Q', 'кью'],
  'r' : ['р', 'r', 'p'],
  's' : ['эс', 'сэ'],
  't' : ['т', 'm', 't'],
  'u' : ['у', 'ю'],
  'v' : ['в','ви','вэ'],
  'w' : ['дабл-ю','даблю'],
  'x' : ['х', 'x', 'h' , 'X', 'Х', 'H', '}{'],
  'y' : ['у', 'y', 'u',  '*'],
  'z' : ['з', '3', 'z','зет','зэт'],
  'ch' : ['ч', 'ch'],
  'sc' : ['ш', 'sh'],  
}



for key, value in d.items():
    #Проходимся по каждой букве в значении словаря. То есть по вот этим спискам ['а', 'a', '@'].
    for letter in value:
        #Проходимся по каждой букве в нашей фразе.
        for phr in phrase:
            #Если буква совпадает с буквой в нашем списке.
            if letter == phr:
                #Заменяем эту букву на ключ словаря.
                phrase = phrase.replace(phr, key)

#Проходимся по всем словам.
for word in words:
    #Разбиваем слово на части, и проходимся по ним.
    for part in range(len(phrase)):
        #Вот сам наш фрагмент.
        fragment = phrase[part: part+len(word)]
        #Если отличие этого фрагмента меньше или равно 25% этого слова, то считаем, что они равны.
        if distance(fragment, word) <= len(word)*0.25:
            #Если они равны, выводим надпись о их нахождении.
            print("Найдено", word, "\nПохоже на", fragment)
```

Comment: Приведите примеры: такое-то на входе, такое-то на выходе, почему вас это не устраивает. И желательно чтобы примеров было несколько хотя бы. А то может быть вы неправильно трактуете происходящее. С Левенштейном вообще нужно обращаться аккуратно.

Comment: Еще могу посоветовать модуль fuzzywuzzy, код будет не таким громоздким и, возможно, там вы найдете решение своей проблемы

Comment: @r3b0rn Да не, тут половина кода преобразует латиницу и всякие козябры в русские буквы, в той библиотеке такого нет, но Левенштейна ей можно заменить, да.